# format the output of awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm writing awk script to determine the number of words.

```
awk '$1 ~/the/ {++c}END{print c}' FS=: br.txt
awk '$1 ~/not/ {++c}END{print c}' FS=: br.txt
awk '$1 ~/that/ {++c}END{print c}' FS=: br.txt
```

And formatting the output, so the heading will be "the not that" and the line under them must be the number of each word. I'm using this:

`awk 'BEGIN { print "the      not    that"

     { printf "%-10s %s\n", $1, $1 }}' br.txt`

The problem is I can't getting the number of words in a row under the the words. What should I change or add?
Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` that should do what you need.

```
awk '$1~/the/ {the++} $1~/not/ {not++} $1~/that/ {that++} END {print "the","not","that\n"the,not,that}' FS=: OFS="\t" br.txt
```

Here is how it works:

```
awk '
    $1~/the/ {the++}                        # If field `1` contains  `the` and `1` to variable `the`
    $1~/not/ {not++}                        # If field `1` contains  `not` and `1` to variable `not`
    $1~/that/ {that++}                      # If field `1` contains  `that` and `1` to variable `that`
END {                                       # When all file is read, do
    print "the","not","that\n"the,not,that} # Print header, and the value of variable  `the,not,that`
' FS=: OFS="\t" br.txt                      # Input field separator = `:`. Output separator = `<tab>`. Read file
```

Answer (score 1):

create separate variables for counts of the words you want to count, all in one awk program, i.e.

```
   awk -F: '$1~/the/{t++} 
        $1~/not/{n++}
        $1~/that/{h++}
       END {
          printf("the\tnot\tthat\n%d\t%d\t%d\n", t,n,h)
       }' br.txt
```

Tested with

```
echo "see the fox
the fox is not here
what is not that" \
|  awk -F: '$1~/the/{t++}
   $1~/not/{n++}
   $1~/that/{h++}
  END {
     printf("the\tnot\that\n%d\t%d\t%d\n", t,n,h)
  }'

the     not     hat
2      2       1
```

Comment: This is not what OP requested.  From OPs example its clear that he like to test field `1` only and not the whole line.  Could easy be fixed by changing `/the/{t++}` to `$1~/the/{t++}`

Comment: @Jotne: yes, you're right. Thanks, I'll fix it. Good luck to all!